# Data Entities Add Range quit working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Like the title suggests I have a small program that has been running in production for the last 3 months.  Last week it started to error out on an AddRange line with this error message:

> "Message=Keyword not supported: 'file'."

And nothing in the inner exception.  Here is the offending function where I can no longer get to the `SaveChanges()` line.

```
private static void SaveToDB(List<MarketNew> inMarketNews) 
{

    proxy.MarketNews.AddRange(inMarketNews);
    proxy.SaveChanges();
}
```

cheers
bob

edit-
If I try to manually add them one at a time I still receive the following exception.

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Keyword not supported: 'file'.
Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
   at GetMarketNews.Program.SaveToDB(List`1 inMarketNews) in e:\Tableau\Custom Utilities\MarketNews\GetMarketNews\GetMarketNews\Program.cs:line 195
```

InnerException:

Comment: Show the full exception

Comment: do you only get this error with `AddRange`? do you also get it with normal queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception indicates that there is a problem with your connection string.  While the program itself may not have been changed in months, can you confirm that the config file (or however you set your connection string) has not been changed?

If you still can't find it from this, I would suggest you check out the value of the connection string at runtime (e.g. put a breakpoint on the AddRange line, and look at `proxy.Database.ConnectionString`).  I suspect you'll find the "file" keyword in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I could not see anything wrong with the connection string even in debug.  But I commented out the old connection and created a new connection string and all was good.

Comment: So finally it would be nice to hear: What was the difference between the your old and your new connection string?

Comment: I can not see anything different, the word 'file' was not in the string.  I am lost as to why it happened.  I am going to chalk it up to gremlins.